# Moving camera on a perspective map

Tags: math, opengl

Given a gesture on a touchscreen which describes a transformation (Scaling + Rotation + Translation), I would like to change the viewmatrix and target position so that the fingers stay sticky to the corresponding points on the map the camera is looking at. 
This is basically the behavior of google maps. This is easy when the direction vector of the camera (eye - target) is perpendicular to the map. However I cannot figure out how to solve this in the case the perspective changes and it is not anymore orthogonal.

Rotation in particular, as far as the direction view is orthogonal to the plane is looking at, is trivial (you rotate target and eye about the unprojected center of rotation from the screen and hence the axis of the viewmatrix). This became tough whenever the orthogonality property gets lost. In fact, in such case, it seems that rotation becomes elliptic and I get lost of where to position the new target.
Any idea?

Comment: Why the downvote? It's an interesting question.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what you mean by "fingers stay sticky on the map"?

Comment: I think what he means is that he's drawing a map à la Google Maps. When you drag with one finger, the projection of that finger onto the map remains in the same position, because the camera is translated (crab). Same with two fingers, because the camera is rotated around the view axis and zoomed. This is straightforward for an orthogonal projection, but how do you do it for a perspective projection if the map is tilted? Is this correct, OP? Or are you still using an orthogonal projection, and only rotate the map?

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is that translating an object under perspective projection doesn't [preserve lengths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometry). If you have a line segment (A,B) in the world coordinate system that is projected onto the screen to (A',B'), and you translate it to (A+v,B+v) in the WCS, you will get points (A'+v1',B'+v2'), and in general v1' will not be equal to v2'. Conversely, if you translate (A',B') to (A'+v',B'+v') on screen, you will not be able to find a translation (A+v0,B+v1) that is projected onto (A'+v',B'+v') where v0 equals v1.

That means the problem is ill-posed. There is not a unique solution. Actually, with an orthogonal projection there's not a unique solution either, since you can always translate the map in the z-direction. But it doesn't matter, because the projection projects along that axis. So with an orthogonal projection it's clear which one of the infinite number of solutions you pick: The one that doesn't alter z. With a perspective projection, it's not clear. It largely depends on how you want the user to be able to navigate.

I think the most intuitive way of dealing with translation gestures would be to rotate the camera. So instead of translating the map you would rotate it around the view origin. One could argue that it's the same for an orthogonal projection: If you convert your camera gradually from a perspective projection to an orthogonal projection, you would move the view origin further and further away while narrowing the field of view, and as you approach infinity the rotation around the view origin becomes a translation that's orthogonal to the viewing direction.

However, the fingers wouldn't be perfectly sticky. For a translation gesture with two fingers, the screen would have to be curved for that. But since it's flat, the perspective distortion will become larger near the border of the screen (distances are distorted more and more). While you could add in some zoom or translation along the view axis to keep the fingers sticky, it might be a little counter-intuitive. I think that's the elliptic movement you mentioned. So I would probably scratch stickiness, and map the translation of the finger's center C to a rotation around the view origin, the rotation of the fingers to a rotation around the view ray through C, and a pinching gesture to a zoom (FOV change).

Whether rotating the camera around its origin is a sensible choice for how you want the user to be able to navigate I can't say. Probably not.