# Non-perspective panning with THREE.PerspectiveCamera

Tags: three.js, perspectivecamera

I'm using the THREE.PerspectiveCamera for use in an orthogonal scene. This is because the THREE.OrthogonalCamera didn't fair well with certain types of interaction. I'm also using THREE's TrackballControls. Zooming and panning the scene all work great for the user so far, but now I've realised I need to move an object into view programatically, and trying to set the camera's x position doesn't just change the camera's x position - it applies perspective too, which I don't want.

I want to move my perspective camera across a 2D plane along the X and Y axes (like panning a map) while looking down the Z axis (at the map).

For a THREE.PerspectiveCamera, setting "camera.position.x += 1000" moves the camera along the x axis by 1000, but also applies perspective to the view by rotating the camera and causes the 2D scene to look skewed. I noticed the camera's rotation and quaternion values have changed.

Initial camera.position at (0,0,5000) looks like this:

[image: Before]

Then setting camera.position.x = 1000, looks like this:

[image: After]

This issue is mentioned in this SO question: [Moving camera on a perspective map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324242/moving-camera-on-a-perspective-map), and I think it's touched on in this SO question: [Three.js & OrbitControls.js - pan camera parallel to ground plane (like Google Earth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185074/three-js-orbitcontrols-js-pan-camera-parallel-to-ground-plane-like-google-e).

I'm not great with matrices and 3D projection, but know the solution is embedded in their workings. I also know that when I drag my map around currently, it *is* panning correctly - [so the solution may also be embedded in the panning code in THREE.TrackballControls](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/controls/TrackballControls.js#L248), but I can't understand it.

Could somebody help me achieve non-perspective "panning" with THREE.PerspectiveCamera?

Comment: don't you just need to move the camera target the same amount as the camera position?

Comment: I see...makes sense, I'll try that and let you know

Comment: Wait, do you mean rotate the target? Because the camera becomes rotated

Comment: no, i meant translation, not rotation, but maybe create a fiddle for your problem to better illustrate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an Orthographic camera.  It's frustum is essentially a perfect cube (rather than the more pyramidal structure formed with the Perspective camera).

This means that all objects will stay the same size no matter how far away they are. (ie. Orthographic camera has no depth perception)

Example of a Perspective camera. Frustum is area between zNear and zFar.
[image]

This is the only performant way to accomplish what you ask.

Now the question becomes: what interactions did not work well with the Orthographic camera?